# Lagrangian Multipliers and a variant of Newton's method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

A variant of Newton's method for solving the equality constrained problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\min &f(x) \\
\text{s.t.} & h(x) = 0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha \left(\nabla_{xx}L(x_k,\lambda_k)\right)^{-1}\nabla_xL(x_k,\lambda_k), \\
\lambda_{k+1} = \lambda_k + \alpha \left(\nabla h(x)^T\nabla_{xx}L(x_k,\lambda_k)\nabla h(x)\right)^{-1} \nabla_{\lambda}L(x_k,\lambda_k),
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $L$ is the augmented Lagrangian function
\begin{equation}
L(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \lambda^{T}h(x) + \frac{\mu}{2}\|h(x)\|^2,
\end{equation}
and $\nabla h(x)^T\nabla_{xx}L(x_k,\lambda_k)\nabla h(x)$ is the dual Hessian.

I am curious about how to prove the global convergence of Newton's method in this scenario. For instance, we can easily prove the convergence of the gradient method:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha \nabla_xL(x_k,\lambda_k), \\
\lambda_{k+1} = \lambda_k + \alpha \nabla_{\lambda}L(x_k,\lambda_k),
\end{array}
\end{equation}

by showing that the gradient norm $\|\nabla L(x,\lambda)\|^2 = \|\nabla_x L(x,\lambda) \|^2 + \|\nabla_\lambda L(x,\lambda) \|^2$ is actually decreasing.

I have tried some numerical experiments and the results show that Newton's method does converge at least linearly. But I don't know how to show that mathematically.

Comment: Or more generally, if we have the updates \begin{equation}x_{k+1} = x_k - A_k \nabla_xL(x_k,\lambda_k), \\ \lambda_{k+1} = \lambda_k + B_k \nabla_\lambda L(x_k,\lambda_k), \end{equation} where $A_k$, $B_k$ are positive definite matrices, can we prove the descent property of the gradient norm $\| \nabla L(x, \lambda)\|$ or some other measurement?